# Apply thick border in Excel for range of cells, not just vertical lines but a grid

Tags: python

```
border1 = borders.Side(style = None, color = 'FF000000', border_style = 'thick')     
border0 = borders.Side(style = None, color = None, border_style = None)   
thick = Border(left = border1, right = border0, bottom = border0, top = border0)

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=4, max_row=9, max_col=4):   
    for cell in row: 
        cell.border = thick
```

This code just applied vertical line but I want it like a grid from C4 to J9.

Comment: Which module for dealing with Excel files did you import? How are `borders` and `Border` and `ws` defined?

Comment: Why did you not also use `border1` for `right` or `bottom` or `top`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what you're trying to achieve or whether you're loading an existing workbook or making one from scratch and draw a grid. If it's the latter, you can try something like below :

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_to_tuple

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active 

MIR, MIC = coordinate_to_tuple("C4")
MAR, MAC = coordinate_to_tuple("J9")
T_BORDER = Side(style="thick")

for row in ws.iter_rows(MIR, MAR, MIC, MAC):
    for cell in row:
        cell.border = Border(*[T_BORDER]*4)

wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: **NB** : In case you're dealing with an *existing spreadsheet*, you can [`load_workbook`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html#openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook).